# How to Pass Parameter to a View and Trigger Redraw on Parameter Change

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI project, and I'm having difficulty passing a parameter to a view and ensuring that the view redraws when the parameter changes. I'm using an @EnvironmentObject (SharedState) to manage shared state across my app.

```swift
// SharedState.swift
class SharedState: ObservableObject {
    // ... other properties ...
    @Published var subTransformationId: String?
    // ... other properties ...
}

// ParentView.swift
struct ParentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedState: SharedState

    var body: some View {
        if sharedState.selectedMenuItem == .transformationEditor,
           let transformationId = sharedState.transformationId,
           let subTransformationId = sharedState.subTransformationId 
        {
            SubTransformationView(transformationId: transformationId, subTransformationId: subTransformationId)
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the condition is not met
            Text("Not in Transformation Editor")
        }
    }
}

// SubTransformationView.swift
struct SubTransformationView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedState: SharedState
    @State private var transformationId: String
    @State private var subTransformationId: String

    var body: some View {
        // ... using subTransformationId ...
    }
}
```

Issue:
I'm struggling with passing the subTransformationId parameter to the SubTransformationView and ensuring that the view redraws when the parameter changes. How can I achieve this in SwiftUI?

Expected Behavior:
I expect the SubTransformationView to receive the subTransformationId parameter and automatically redraw when the parameter changes.

Additional Information:

I have correctly set up the @EnvironmentObject in the parent view.
The SharedState is injected into the view hierarchy using the .environmentObject modifier.

Comment: Did you try using `sharedState.subTransformationId` in the sub view, that is from the environment object? Otherwise you need to use Binding and not State for a property in a sub view that gets passed from a parent view.

Comment: Using from `sharedState.subTransformationId` would work, but I would do on the other way, that is more "web" like.

Comment: It is the opposite, I removed `@State` and now view updates.

Comment: Ah, i thought you wanted to update the property

Comment: shared state is a bad idea since in SwiftUI state is designed to be spread across the View structs

Answer (score 1):

If the ids are used as read-only in the child view then just define them with `let`. The parent is observing changes, so it will re-create the child when an id changes.

```swift
// SubTransformationView.swift
struct SubTransformationView: View {
    // @EnvironmentObject var sharedState: SharedState // not needed?
    let transformationId: String
    let subTransformationId: String

    // other content as before
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're indicating that any views that modify this variable will be noticed when it changes by using @Published. I think `ParentView` was set up correctly. However, in the `SubTransformationView`, declaring transformationId and subTransformationId as `@State` seems like the wrong way to go. @State means that the view holds value, I believe you might be confused with `@Binding`. So, there are a few approaches to fix it:

Approach 1: Replacing with @Binding. It appears to be acceptable as well, but you're injecting `SharedState` and it's a little bit redundant. So I prefer approach 2.

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedState: SharedState
    var body: some View {
        ...
        SubTransformationView(
             transformationId: $sharedState.transformationId, 
             subTransformationId: $sharedState.subTransformationId
        )
    }
}

struct SubTransformationView: View {
    @Binding var transformationId: String?
    @Binding var subTransformationId: String?
    ...
}
```

Approach 2: Using properties directly from `SharedState`

```swift
struct SubTransformationView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedState: SharedState
    var body: some View {
        /*Something like
        if let subId = shareState.subTransformationId {
            ... another sub view
        } else {
            ... an alert view
        }
        */
    }
}
```